# Typo / Missing link on privileges page for "create gallery chat rooms"

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks, privileges

Meta Stack Overflow has the link correctly, but SO, SU, and the betas I looked at all had the `chat.example.com` listed with no link:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SU](https://superuser.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms), and all the betas I checked now have functional links.

Comment: Well done! nice catch!